# async: false ajax, зависает хром

Tags: jquery, ajax, асинхронность

Помогите обернуть ajax запрос, чтобы он выполнялся последовательно async: false подвисает браузер, пробовал обернуть в функцию, но вылетают ошибки.

```
          $(document.getElementById('process')).on("click", function(e) {
          if (last_date_chk > new Date().getTime()) {
              getConfirm('<div style="padding:25px"><legend style="text-align:center;padding:10px!important">Невозможно обновить данные</legend><p>С момента последнего обновления данных <b>не прошло 20 минут.</b></p><p>Попробуйте повторить действие чуть позже, либо воспользуйтесь последними полученными данными.</p></div>', function(result) {});
          } else {
              var offers = [<?php echo '"' . implode('","', $offers[0]) . '"'; ?>],
                  offersDone = 0,
                  gmtDate = new Date,
                  timeOffset = gmtDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60,
                  localDate = (new Date(gmtDate.getTime() - 36E5 * timeOffset)).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');


              if (clkBtnProgressbar == 0) {
                  clkBtnProgressbar = 1;

                  $('.progress').animate({
                      opacity: 'toggle'
                  }, {
                      duration: 2000,
                      start: function() {
                          $(this).css('display', 'block');
                      }
                  });
                  for (i = 0; i <= offers.length; ++i) {
                      $.ajax({
                          type: 'GET',
                          url: URL_SELF,
                          async: true,
                          data: {
                              buy_product_id: offers[i],
                              buy_product_date: localDate
                          }
                      }).done(function() {
                          ++offersDone;
                          $('.progress-bar').css('width', (offersDone / offers.length) * 100 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', (offersDone / offers.length) * 100);
                      });
                  }
              } else {
                  getConfirm('<h2 class="text-center">Ждите…</h2>', function(result) {});
              }
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Элементарное решение:

```
var i = 0;
function query() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: URL_SELF,
        async: true,
        data: {
            buy_product_id: offers[i],
            buy_product_date: localDate
        }
    }).done(function() {
        ++offersDone;
        $('.progress-bar').css('width', (offersDone / offers.length) * 100 + '%').attr('aria-valuenow', (offersDone / offers.length) * 100);
        if (++i < offers.length) { 
          query();
        }
    });
}

if (offers.length) query();
```

*Немного оффтопа:*
Вместо
`[<?php echo '"' . implode('","', $offers[0]) . '"'; ?>]`
предпочтительнее использовать что-то вроде
`<?php echo json_encode(array_values($offers[0]));?>`

Comment: *Тогда ещё немного оффтопа:*  
Лучше так: `<?=json_encode(array_values($offers[0]));?>` :)

Comment: vp_arth, спасибо большое за помощь! Все отлично теперь работает!  json_encode array_values, возьму на заметку!

Comment: TheDoctor, short_open_tag=On :-)

Comment: @TheDoctor, это только если включены `short_open_tag`. Иногда это становится отдельным геморроем для новичков.

Comment: @vp_arth, угу, правда геморроя я не испытывал, когда только делал первые шаги.  
Короткая запись часто включена, а если что - включить легко.

Answer (score 0):

Я вам крайне не рекомендуя делать `async: false`, что-бы упорядочить ответы от сервера, можно попробовать обернуть её в `$.deferred();`, в трёх словах не объяснить, но есть очень хорошая статья тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/113073/